# how is the redirect rule from https://www.domain to http://domain?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

this is
http to https
non www to www

```
#http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#add www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I dont know reverse code ^^;;
https to http
www to non www

how is the rule in htaccess?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `https` to `http` and `www` to `non-www` you can modify your rules like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
#https -> http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#add non-www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```